# Using Typescript/Angular to hide HTML elements with RXJS

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom, rxjs

There are divs that display recipes (from a  property on the component in an object array - 'Recipes', 'Recipes' includes a property 'Recipes.diet' that is a string of diets), I have a filterf component that sends subscriptions of diets (currently 'Vegetarian,'GlutenFree','Vegan'). I want to hide recipes that include the diet keyword e.g. an observable of 'Vegetarian' hides all recipes that don't have the 'Vegetarian' keyword included in their 'diet' property.

Currently I'm not getting difference.
I've tried using angular ngClass, ngStyle to dynamically filter the class lists to includes '.hide' (which sets the display to none).

When I statically set the display to 'none' it's successful, I'm currently trying a method that manipulates the Dom directly through HTML Element objects but that isn't working either.

I've checked that the keywords are coming through, and they're matching up successfully with the correct divs. I've tried just setting the style attribute through typescript and adding a class type (this is the method I'm trying below).

I know this will be a very simple issue but I've run out of ways to check, I've searched online and StackOverflow & tried about every variations of DOM/Angular changing I can think of.

HTML:

```
 <div *ngFor="let recipe of recipes" id="{{recipe.title}}-card" (click)="recipeWasChosen(recipe)">
    <app-recipe-title class="recipe-card" [recipe]="recipe">
    </app-recipe-title>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
this.recipeService.recipeRestrictions.subscribe((restrictions: string[]) => {
      this.recipes.forEach((recipe: Recipe) => {
        let hide = false;
        for (const restriction of restrictions) {
          if (!recipe.diet.includes(restriction)) {
            hide = true;
          }
        }
        if (hide) {
          this.hideCardWithHTMLElement(recipe.title);
        } else this.hideCardWithHTMLElement(recipe.title);
      });
    });

  hideCardWithHTMLElement(title: string) {
    let card = document.getElementById(`${title}card`);
    if (card.classList.contains('hidden')) {
      card.className = '';
    } else card.className = 'hidden';
  }
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to filter your list by type of restriction, You don't need to hide the elements, but you can filter out the ones that contain restrictions in general .you can do something like this

```
this.recipes$ = this.recipeService.recipeRestrictions
.pipe(
   map((restrictions: string[]) => {
      return this.recipes.filter((recipe) => restrictions.every((restriction) => !recipe.diet.includes(restriction)))
   })
)
```

and in template

```
<div *ngFor="let recipe of recipes$ | async">
...
</div>
```

Comment: I like the concept behind this, I was using async with the template before. This isn't working though, I then tried turning the 'recipes' into 'recipes$' with the 'of' operator but still nothing showed. To combine the initial subscription to 'recipes' with the async sub of 'recipes$' which is then operated on with the 'restrictions', all while displaying on template, it may work but that is above my understanding of RxJs.

Comment: My attempt, doesn't work though.    `this.recipeService.getCurrentRecipesWithinPriceRange(this.tier).subscribe((recipes: Recipe[]) => this.recipes = recipes);
    this.recipeService.recipeRestrictions.subscribe((restrictions) => {
      this.recipes.filter((recipe) => {
        restrictions.every((restriction) => !recipe.diet.includes(restriction))
      });
    });`

Comment: check your conditions. I created an example for you on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lwqfyl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you! I discovered at least that Stackblitz isn't operating on my firefox properly so that's an improvement, I've also improved my post to better communicate the solution I intend. There are two subscriptions, one of recipes:Recipe that is updated depending on misc aspects(e.g price range), & one of restrictions: string[] that is supposed to effect the displayed Recipes when restrictions emits.

Comment: The following code doesn't have one subscription effecting the other, even though with logging I can see the 'restriction' subscription is followed by the second subscription of recipes

Comment: [code mentioned in previous comment - pastebin](https://pastebin.com/uq7JdFy3) I feel there must be a solution, I tried combineLatest but even with a dummy initial value for the restrictions so that both subs have one emission it wouldn't work [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/77t3FcMR)

Comment: [check it out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lwqfyl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: That works but doesn't represent the environment, this is closer to the actual environment (but doesn't work) [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uvkg8m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: [check it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1nv4mw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you! I apologize as it was a bit of an xy problem, the diet was a part of a group form that was causing the recipes to be refreshed overriding the filtering. I split them apart and it works, though your implementation of the filtering is cleaner though so I'll use it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a [*ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) to dynamically hide a recipe based on its hide status?
Since you can't add a *ngFor and *ngIf on the same container you can use a [ng-container](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-ng-container-element) like this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let recipe of recipes" id="{{recipe.title}}-card" (click)="recipeWasChosen(recipe)">
    <ng-container *ngIf="isFiltered(receipe)">
        <app-recipe-title class="recipe-card" [recipe]="recipe"></app-recipe-title>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

the isFiltered(receipe) method is your filter which returns either true or false depending on the recipe is filtered or not.

Also make sure to avoid manipulating the DOM over java script (better use ngIf directives) since this can lead to problems.

Comment: Attempted yes, though using divs instead of ng-container (a better option that I wasn't aware of, thank you!), I was hoping that'd make the difference but it hasn't, filtering is still not having an effect. This is what I tried: 
HTML:
`<div *ngFor="let recipe of recipes" id="{{recipe.title}}-card" (click)="recipeWasChosen(recipe)">
    <ng-container *ngIf="hideCard(recipe.title)">
      <app-recipe-title class="recipe-card" [recipe]="recipe">
      </app-recipe-title>
    </ng-container>
  </div>`
TS:
[pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/yf204Kb5)

Comment: [calling function in angular template is bad idea](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496)